# Задания агента SQL-server

Tags: sql-server

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в задании один шаг выполнялся по одному расписанию, а другой - по другому расписанию, то есть чтобы шаги друг от друга не зависели?

Comment: а два задания не сделать что ли?

Comment: Автор, у вас все получилось? Может остались вопросы?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko да, всё получилось, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Можно - для этого надо сделать 2 джоба следующим способом:

1. Первый Job должен стартовать со 2 шага выполняясь по расписанию №1.
2. Для шага №1 необходимо установить настройку завершения джоба при успешном выполнении, если вы не хотите, чтобы шаг №2 выполнялся по 2 расписаниям.
3. Второе задание будет вызывать с помощью процедуры `sp_start_job` Джоб №1 c шага №1 по расписанию №2.

Но смысла в таком решения я не вижу, но может быть, если бы вы описали задачу целиком - смысл стал бы понятен.